# How does the user push API work

Tags: oauth, foursquare

The foursquare user push API states

> The user push API will push to your application every time a user who has granted access to your OAuth consumer checks in.

I have created a consumer and set up a webapp to handle the pushed notifications, however what I dont understand is how and where will the user grant access to my consumer? 
So for example if a user checkins to a shop, I will get a notification only if the user has granted access to my consumer, but how will be user even know about my consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the user to authorize your app on foursquare.
This is **very** similar to the way it works with Facebook.

Try looking here for some help with this: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth

After your users authorize your app (consumer), you can see the [Realtime API docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime) on how to get it working and process the posts done by foursquare.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess what I was really looking for was a venue push which is not currently available. I am trying to work directly on top of foursquare without having to create an explicit app. As per http://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/browse_thread/thread/801932c6d2337e7e this API is not available.

Comment: There is a Venue Push API available at the Realtime API docs Sajid linked to. In order to use it, however, you need to have a consumer key that's been authorized by the manager of the venue you wish to track.